# If $\{A_n,n\geq 1\}$ are independent events show that $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} 1_{A_i}-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(A_i) \rightarrow^{P} 0$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

If $\{A_n,n\geq 1\}$ are independent events show that
$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} 1_{A_i}-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(A_i) \rightarrow^{P} 0$$.

## Proof so far

$P(|\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} 1_{A_i}-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(A_i)|\geq \epsilon)=P(|\frac{1}{n} \big( \sum_{i=1}^{n} 1_{A_i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(A_i)\big)|\geq \epsilon)=P(|\big( \sum_{i=1}^{n} 1_{A_i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(A_i)\big)|\geq n \epsilon)\leq \frac{E\big(\sum_{i=1}^{n} 1_{A_i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(A_i)\big)}{n\epsilon}$

Comment: Should I simply the right hand side some more

Comment: Weak Law of Large Numbers applied to $1_{A_i}-P(A_i)$.

Answer (score 4):

It is equivalent to show that
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i \to_P 0.$$
where $X_i = I_{A_i} - P(A_i) = I_{A_i} - E(I_{A_i})$ are independent and of zero mean. By independence, it follows that
\begin{align}
& \text{Var}\left(\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i\right) \\
= & \sum_{i = 1}^n\text{Var}(X_i) \\
= & \sum_{i = 1}^n E(X_i^2) \\
= & \sum_{i = 1}^n P(A_i)(1 - P(A_i)) \\
\leq & \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{[P(A_i) + 1 - P(A_i)]^2}{4} \\
= & \frac{1}{4}n 
\end{align}
where we used the algebraic-geometric inequality
$$ab \leq \frac{1}{4}(a + b)^2.$$
Therefore by Chebyshev's inequality, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, 
\begin{align}
& P\left[\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i\right| > \varepsilon\right] \\
= & P\left[\left|\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i\right| > n\varepsilon\right] \\
\leq & \frac{\text{Var}\left(\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i\right)}{n^2\varepsilon^2} \\
\leq & \frac{\frac{1}{4}n}{n^2\varepsilon^2} \\
= & \frac{1}{4n\varepsilon^2} \to 0
\end{align}
as $n \to \infty$.